# How can I manage sub-group access in npm registry

Tags: npm, npm-registry

When using `npm registry` to publish private project, I found that I can't control the access for each `scoped` package. If I grant an access to an account for the organization, this account will have access to all packages under this organization. Is there a way to manage scope-level access control?